# how to get intellisense work in SQL server 2008 R2 with Visual studio sp1?

Tags: sql-server

After a long time i test SQL server for work. I download express editon and found that intelisese not worked. I found that SQL server sp1 need to take update after installing SP1. I search a lot on google and bing never found that something help me. Can someone tell me how i can solve this issue. how i can got update my sql server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft released a patch for this issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2507770